# Storing a User's Statistics In a Table. which of these two methods should i be using?

Tags: php, mysql

What's the best way to store site statistics for specific users? Basically I want to store how many times a user has done a specific task. The data will be coming from a potentially large table and will be referenced frequently, so I want to avoid COUNT() and store them in their own table.

**Method A**

Have a table with the following fields, then have a row for each user to store the count for each field:

```
User_id | posted_comments | comment_replies | post_upvotes | post_downvotes
50        12                7                 23             54
```

**Method B**

Have one table storing the actions, and another storing the count for that action:

Table 1:

```
Id | Action
1  | posted_comments
2  | comment_replies
3  | post_upvotes
4  | post_downvotes
```

Table 2

```
User_id | Action | Count
50      | 1      | 12
50      | 2      | 7
50      | 3      | 23
50      | 4      | 54
```

I can't see me having more than 25-30 actions in total, but I'm not sure if that is too many to store horizontally as in method A.

Comment: If you're working with a discrete and manageable set of statistics, the I'd recommend Method A (especially as you're concerned about performance)... if you're likely to want to add further statistics in the foreseeable future, then Method B would probably be the better approach

Comment: @MarkBaker Method B with a compound index on `User_id` and `Action` would surely be very performant as well? Though I agree with your answer overall.

Comment: I'd also assume that the OP will be using triggers to update the values within a transaction

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your question.  If you don't know what the actions are, then store each action in a separate row.  That would be the second option.

Be sure that you have the proper indexes on the table.  One possibility is `(user_id, action, count)`.  With this index, it will be fast to denormalize the table at the user level.

If you have a well-defined problem and won't need to be adding/removing/renaming columns in a table, then the first version is also feasible.  Otherwise, just stick with inserting rows.  The queries may seem a little bit more complicated, but the application is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typical BI question to me. The real question is not how many "actions" you have in your dimension, but how often they change.

Table A is denormalized and quick and easy to read: with a "SELECT" you get your information in the proper format.

Table B is normalized and easier to maintain It is highly recommended if your list of actions difficult to defined in advance, and is a **must** if it is dynamic.

To pass back and forth from Table A to Table B is known as pivot operations, for which you find standard tools, but which are never easy to code manually. So do not jump too quickly to the conclusion that Table B is better just because every body tells so since Codd in 1970.

I suggest you to ask yourself the question of how often will your COUNT(*) table(s) will be read. If you can live with the statistics of yesterday, then compute BOTH tables every night.